# How to send local notification everyday on a specific time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to send notification to user (local notification) at 10.11 am everyday.
I have done the following:

In MainActivity.java, I have a button click listener to trigger the alarm (um not sure if it was necessary). Ok the button has this code:

```
public void notifyMattie(View view) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("MY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

    }
```

I also have another class called: NotificationReceiver.java, It looks like:

```
package coinchain.com.coinchain;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,Invest.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("Notification text")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (intent.getAction().equals("MY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE")){
            notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this on real device I do not see any notification. where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple scheduler, I recommend adding quartz. It is very easy to set up.

Documentation: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Be careful, the time is in UTC(for CronSheduler)

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Job.java

```
public class Job implements Job {
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("This is a quartz job!");
}}
```

Main.java must contain

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                  .newJob(Job.class)
                  .withIdentity("SimpleJob")
                  .build();

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                       .newTrigger()
                       .withIdentity("SimpleJob")
                       .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 11 10 * * ?"))
                       .build();

Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: OP's tag and code is `Android`. Does Quartz support Android?